# Next.js - Routing from nested component

Tags: next.js

I'm not sure how should I resolve the nested routing issue in Next.js.

This is my dir structure:

```
pages
   |-[category]
   |     |-index.js
   |     |-[city]
   |        |-index.js
   |-post
   |   |-[id].js
   index.js
```

All code is implemented in `index.js` in `pages` folder with a list of posts with their city and category set up in the database. Clicking on any of these posts should redirect you to `domain.com/post/some-id`.

I'm using a filter bar on the front-end with tags that use different queries. So clicking on *"Category 1"* tag should display the same website but with filtered data AND a new URL (`domain.com/category-1/`). You could filter out the data even further by clicking on the city tag (clicking *"New York"* should redirect you to `domain.com/category-1/new-york`). You could also remove the tag with the category which should now redirect you to `domain.com/all/new-york`). Removing both filters (category and city) should redirect you to `domain.com`, not `domain.com/all/all`.

**Question:**

1. When I am on the main page (`index.js` in `pages`) and I click on one of the posts it properly redirects me to the post details page ([id].js). But when I am in any of the nested routes (i.e. earlier mentioned `domain.com/category-1/new-york`) clicking on post causes this error:

[image: Next.js routing error]

There is no need to set any category, I just want to be redirected to the details page of that post. It seems like I can't get out of the nested route. How could I solve this?

Comment: Could you post the code related to the error you're seeing?